# Invalid input syntax for type inet

Tags: django, postgresql

Im having trouble persisting ip_addresses from my users via Django into Postgres.  Can I just convert the ip_address field from inet to string and store that in the VARCHAR postgres field?

Comment: What trouble do you have?

Comment: My ORM (django) is throwing the exception in the title when I pass an IP address

Comment: What does the value look like?

Comment: "fe80::8019:67ff:fed1:a54c%p2p0"

Comment: Yes, that is not an IP address. PostgreSQL is right to complain. Since it is not an IP address, `text` is a proper data type.